# RewriteMap with mappings ignoring case

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The current vhost_config.conf has mapping and rewrite rules that work, and is shown below.

```
1: RewriteMap vanityURL txt: vanity_map.txt
2: RewriteCond ${vaintyURL:$1|not-found} ^(.+)$
3: RewriteCond %1 ~^not-found$
4: RewriteRule ^/(.*) /${vanityURL:$1|/$1} [L]
```

What I need to happen is for the mapped URLS to ignore case.

First thing you'll say is "add `[NC]`" and you'd be correct to think that, but it doesn't have any effect.

I've seen questions talking about bringing all of the mappings in as lowercase, but that doesn't solve the problem where someone types in `/BlackFriday` or `/BlaCKFridAY` (for whatever reason one might be compelled to do such a thing).

The problem I'm having is that using a line such as

```
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) /${vanityURL:$1|/$1} [L, NC]
```

has no impact.

Do I need to have the `[NC]` flag earlier in one of the conditions or in the map declaration?

Why wouldn't the 'ignore-case' flag on line 4 work?
Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Hm, does nesting work? Never tried it, but something like `RewriteMap lc int:tolower`, &  `${vanityURL:${lc:$1}}`?

Comment: If that did work, now all mapped URLs are lower case, not case insensitive.
That would leave the basic problem remaining.

Comment: Erm, you are _replacing_ that part of the url. You are only matching against forced lowercase. The replacement has a fixed case, doesn't it?

Comment: I've taken the liberty to test it, and it just... works... I'll add the details in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works here:

list 'o urls `list.txt`

```
 test1 POMPOM
 test2 pompom
 test3 PomPom
```

apache host config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteMap test txt:/var/www/list.txt
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /${test:${lc:$1}|$1} [R=301]
```

(external redirect so it's easier observable in this test)

This means:

```
example.com/TEST1 
example.com/test1
example.com/TeSt1
```

... all redirect to `example.com/POMPOM`

```
example.com/TEST2 
example.com/test2
example.com/TeSt2
```

... all redirect to `example.com/pompom`

...  so the case of the replacement is preserved,